# How to run tlmgr in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tlmgr, texlive-2018

I installed TexLive from https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have `tlmgr`

```
which tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux//tlmgr
```

I try

```
tlmgr install tex-gyre
```

and get:

```
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2018/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Trying

```
sudo tlmgr install tex-gyre
```

I get

```
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

Trying `sudo su` first I get

```
Command 'tlmgr' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install texlive-base
```

How to perform this operation?

Comment: It is not found because it is not in the path.

Comment: What are the permissions of this folder? What does `ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2018/` say?

Comment: You can call it passing the path `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

Comment: I suspect that you didn't add binaries to the PATH after installed TeXlive.

Comment: @Sigur, adding `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/` after doing `sudo su` worked

Comment: @Viesturs, usually we add `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH, export PATH ` (or x86 of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$PATH` used by `sudo` is different from the one used by `$USER`, so if the `$PATH` does not include, in your case, the path `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/`, then `sudo` will not be able to find `tlmgr`.

---

On Ubuntu, <strike>I highly recommend that</strike> you *can* install texlive via `apt`. See [the Ubuntu package database](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive) for a list of all packages related to texlive. Also, from the same domain as you provided, they have [a page](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) specifically written for Debian-based (which Ubuntu is based on) systems. If you choose to install the full distribution of texlive, you will not have to install texlive packages using `tlmgr` and just let `apt` (the package manager for Debian-based systems) handle that for you. Otherwise, you will only need to run `tlmgr` with the `sudo` command, except now the distribution from `apt` should provide a symlink (or equivalent) to a path that your root account refers to.

However, as pointed out in the subcomments, texlive on `apt` is possibly outdated.

---

If disk space is a serious concern, and/or if you are comfortable with the command line, I highly recommend that you install `tlmgr` as a user instead of root. Follow the [guide from Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation#Minimal_installation) for a minimal installation process. Last time I checked, the guide is still up to date. The important point to install `tlmgr` so that it does not require root access is the following:

> 3. You may want to change the directory options. For example you may want to hide your personal macro folder which is located at TEXMFHOME. It is ~/texmf by default. Replace it by ~/.texmf to hide it.

You will need to change the default `/usr/local/` to your home directory.

If disk space is not of your concern, then just choose the full distribution schema.

---

Edits:
See also @daleif's comment under this reply, especially these two sentences:

> Ubuntu texlive is quite out of date and split into a myriad of Ubuntu packages. So a lot of users do not recommended using the apt version

Just more information for you to watch out for when deciding which installation path you wish to go down.

Comment: Note that the Ubuntu texlive is quite out of date and split into a myriad of Ubuntu packages. So a lot of users do _not_ recommended using the apt version. Figuring out which unubutu texlive package to install to get a given latex package is a pain.

Comment: Thanks for the info @daleif. I don't use a Debian-based distribution myself so I am not aware of that. I'll put a note in my answer.

Comment: It is an issue with most Linux dists that provide TeXLive. Some even take TeXLive year X before it is released, and thus may ship one that contains errors.

Comment: I suppose that its a problem that stems from the philosophy that goes behind distributing packages on a distribution, though it may be the case that this applies only to how texlive is being handled. That said, [archlinux](https://sources.archlinux.org/other/texlive/) seems to keep its repo updated.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question was long answered already, nevertheless I think that my answer will prove to be useful for those that do not want to use `apt` to install each latex package.

If you install TexLive through the [scrip of the TexLive installation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) you can call the UI in the following ways:

When installed as a system wide application:

```
user@device:~$ sudo tlmgr -gui
```

But this will not find an installation in your user space, most logically you would try dropping the `sudo` command. However, this will not work as it requires sudo access. Perform the following steps to open the local installation with admin rights:

```
user@device:~$ which tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
user@device:~$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr -gui
```

Your `which` command might get a different location, use the location that your computer reports.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!